# Locate point on edge of two quads

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, geometry

In Unity, I have two objects on my UI Canvas. I am trying to draw a line that starts at the edge of one object and ends at the edge of another, dynamically. I can think of one way to do this:

With a line from the center of each object, find the points where the line intersects with the edges of the objects. In the screenshot below, these would be the yellow and violet dots.

[image: Photoshopped reference]

Does anyone have any pointers on how to code this? I'm having trouble locating the points of intersection. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What type of UI Object? Image, RawImage??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let centers of rectangles has coordinates `(acx,acy)` and `(bcx, bcy)`, rectangle widths and heights are `aw, ah, bw, bh`.

Find center difference

```
(dx, dy) = (bcx-acx, bcy-acy)
```

Line intersects vertical edge of A rectangle if

```
Abs(dx) * ah >= Abs(dy) * aw
```

(and horizontal edge otherwise)

If `dx>0`, it is right edge, intersection point x-coordinate is `A.right`, otherwise it is `A.left`.
And you have to solve equation (due to triangle similarity) to find intersection point y-coordinate

```
aw/2 / Abs(dx) = (aintersection.y - acy) / dy
aintersection.y = acy + aw * dy / (2*dx)
```

Consider horizontal edge cases by analogy

Comment: Fantastic! This is a much more elegant solution that what I was attempting. My attempt involved calculating angles to find what edge of the squares the line was intersecting. What a mess. Thanks a ton!